# How to install the latest openjdk 12 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, apt-get

I've installed the default jdk by issuing the command:

```
apt-get install default-jdk
```

This will install openjdk 11 and apt-get seems to install the files all over the place. Examples:

```
/etc/java-11-openjdk/management
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/JAVA_HOME
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openjdk-11-jre:amd64.postinst
```

As you can see by the example locations above, there are files scattered everywhere.

I've just installed a web app that's giving a warning that it only supports jdk 12 (I think it's the latest openjdk version). How can I install version 12 so that it replaces version 11? What is the best way to upgrade the openjdk version on Ubuntu 18.04 so that it doesn't mingle with the previous version?

Comment: Maybe docker can help you. Try `ubuntu:19.04` image.

Answer (score 32):

This works for me:

1. Download archive with wget or go to the [JDK 12 GA Release](http://jdk.java.net/12) site and download the archive manually:

```
wget https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk12.0.2/e482c34c86bd4bf8b56c0b35558996b9/10/GPL/openjdk-12.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
```

2. Create the /usr/java directory:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/java
```

3. Move archive to the new directory:

```
mv openjdk-12.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz /usr/java
```

4. Go to this directory:

```
cd /usr/java
```

5. Unpack archive:

```
sudo tar -xzvf openjdk-12.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
```

6. Set the environment variables, for this open the /etc/profile file:

```
sudo nano /etc/profile
```

7. And add the following code to the end of this file:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk-12.0.2
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

8. Configure Java commands to use the newly JDK by default:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/java/jdk-12.0.2/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/java/jdk-12.0.2/bin/javac" 1
```

9. Check Java version:

```
java -version
```

If you previously had another version of Java installed and the version has not changed, try to run the following command and to select the desired version:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: Adding JAVA_HOME to /etc/profile would tie me to use jdk12 ? What if I want multiple java versions and java_home is automatically set when I do a `update-alternatives --config java` ?

Comment: don't export the path it is impractical, use update-alternatives all the time to switch java, if you are in real imperfect software development world you will unfortunately have project on different versions. And in this particular case 12 is not even LTS, so set the path to LTS at least.

Comment: This breaks sdkmanager for me. java -version is `openjdk version "12.0.2" 2019-07-16`, but sdkmanager throws `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema`. Any thoughts on a simple solution for this?

Comment: @MattLarson I resolved this problem by replacing my sdkmanager installation with the command line tools: https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools

See this dockerfile for an example on how to install and use it: https://github.com/bitrise-io/android/blob/master/Dockerfile

Answer (score -2):

The official package repository from Ubuntu doesn't provide a Openjdk12 package because openjdk11 is the last version of the openjdk package for your version.

Comment: Yes, I've already tried that. I'm trying to find the best way to install openjdk 12 without clobbering the jdk 11 files that already exist. And I suspect that I'll need to switch to alternative as well.

Comment: @u84six you could upgrade your LTS version to the latest non-lts version 19.04

Comment: I'm using aws EC2 and they don't support anything newer than 18.04.

Comment: I think what I'll unfortunately have to do is uninstall the default jdk, and manually install oracle jdk 12. Ugh. Good ol' Linux.

Comment: @u84six you could also install the openjdk manuelly https://openjdk.java.net/install/